# Magento 2 Products not found during Catalog Search reindex

Tags: full-text-search, visibility, magento2, reindex, large-data

We are working on Magento 2.1.0

We are facing an issue of no products found during catalog search reindexing. As we have a large catalog, this process is taking a good time to get completed and during that time website is not showing any products.

Please help if anyone has faced this kind of issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to check your category.

Is there only one **main/root** category?

You cant have two main/roots.

Like:

> **allproducts**
>
> > bags
> >
> > > sportbag
> > >
> > > shopingbag
> > >
> > > outdoor-bag
> >
> > shoes
> >
> > > sportshoes
> > >
> > > xxx
> >
> > xyz
> >
> > > xxx